# SpringBoot datasource and manual sharding

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to connect a SpringBoot App to a legacy database system with manual sharding management.

With a carId given by a user, I can locate the shard where the car is saved.
(examples: carId=1 is in shard 1, carId=2 is in shard2)

I do not know how to do it in a proper way (autowiring?, Datasource?, ..).

Can you help me?

My application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CarApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CarApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My controller

```
@RestController
public class CarController {

    @Autowired
    CarService carService;

    @GetMapping("/car/{carId}")
    public Optional<Car> car(
            @PathVariable(value = "carId") String carId
    ) {
        return carService.getTransaction(carId);
    }
}
```

My service

```
public class CarService {

    @Autowired
    private CarJpaRepository carJpaRepository;

    public Optional<Car> getCar(String carId) {
        Optional<Car> car = carJpaRepository.findById(carId);
        return car;
    }
}
```

My Repository

```
public interface CarJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Long> {

}
```

My configuration

```
spring.shard1.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.shard1.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shard1?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.shard1.username=root
spring.shard1.password=root

spring.shard2.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.shard2.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shard2?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.shard2.username=root
spring.shard2.password=root

spring.shard3.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.shard3.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shard3?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.shard3.username=root
spring.shard3.password=root

spring.shard4.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.shard4.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shard4?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.shard4.username=root
spring.shard4.password=root
```

Comment: This [post](https://medium.com/innomizetech/dynamic-multi-database-application-with-spring-boot-7c61a743e914) could be relevant for you. You will need to have a routing data source which will depends on this thread's context (namely, the shard you will want to query). Setting the context can either be done explicitly or by aspect oriented programming.